# Django - Python :: How to pass a variable to another page on Render/Redirect

Tags: python, django, variables, redirect, response

I have a login page A, in which I take User/Pwd info, and post to another 3rd party website and get a sessionid variable in JSON format. When I redirect/render ingestion page B I need this sessionid variable to be displayed/available there.

This is what I've tried, but I can't seem to get it to work. Can someone help please?

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from loginp.views import LoginView
from loginp.views import IngestionView

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(),name='LoginView'),
    path('ingestion/', IngestionView.as_view(template_name='registration/ingestion.html'),name='IngestionView'),]
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import LoginForm
from .forms import IngestionForm
import json
import requests

class LoginView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'registration/login.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

def post(self, request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        #print form.cleaned_data()
        text = form.cleaned_data['email']
        pwd = form.cleaned_data['password']

    data = {
     "@type": "login",
     "username": text,
     "password": pwd
    }


    data_json = json.dumps(data)
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    url='https://cloud.com/ma/api/v2/user/login'
    response = requests.post(url, data=data_json, headers=headers)
    sessionid=response.json()['icSessionId']

    form1 = IngestionForm()
    #return render(request,'registration/ingestion.html',{'sessionid':sessionid}) #{'info':args})
    #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('IngestionView', kwargs={'sessionid':sessionid}))
    return redirect(request,'registration/ingestion.html',sessionid=sessionid) 


class IngestionView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'registration/ingestion.html'


def post(self, request):
    form1 = IngestionForm(request.POST)

    args1 = {"form": form1}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args1)
```

login.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container">
        <div class="login-form col-md-4 offset-md-4">
            <h4 class="title">Please Login</h4>
            <br>
            <form action="{% url 'IngestionView' %}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group" >
              {% csrf_token %}  
              {{form.as_p}}     
              <br>
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value='submit'>login</button>
             </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ingestion.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ingestion Details</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container">
            <h4 class="title">Ingestion Details</h4>
            <br>
            <form method="POST">    
            <div class="form-group" >
              {% csrf_token %}  
              {{ form.as_p }}       
              <br>
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value='submit'>Do something</button>

             </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
<h2>Session Id {{ sessionid }}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

<-----New Code----->
views.py

```
data_json = json.dumps(data)
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
url='https://dm-us.informaticacloud.com/ma/api/v2/user/login'
response = requests.post(url, data=data_json, headers=headers)
sessionid=response.json()['icSessionId']
request.session['sessionid'] = sessionid
request.session.save()
form1 = IngestionForm()
return render(request,'registration/ingestion.html',{'sessionid':sessionid}) #{'info':args})
```

ingestion.html

```
<h2>Session Id {{ request.session.get('sessionid') }}</h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save this value to Django's [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/). In first view:

```
sessionid=response.json()['icSessionId']
request.session['sessionid'] = sessionid
```

In second view:

```
class IngestionView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'registration/ingestion.html'


    def post(self, request):
        form1 = IngestionForm(request.POST)
        sessionid=request.session['sessionid']
        args1 = {"form": form1, 'sessionid': sessionid}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args1)
```

Comment: Thank you @neverwalkaloner. Will try this now. I have a doubt. Will maintaining session variables cause a problem if 2 different users login? How will I be able to track 2 users separately?

Comment: @sammydude Django will do it for you. Each user have different session data.

Comment: Thanks @neverwalkaloner! Sorry for the noob questions :) So I tried to include the above code in the views. View 1 - before redirecting I assigned the session variable. How do I access it? I tried to access the variable directly in the 2nd page HTML and didn't get a value.

Comment: @sammydude can you add code to the question? Its unreadable in the comment.

Comment: Sorry. Realized and added new code in the bottom of the main section. Also can we access the session variable the same way in the POST section of the 2nd view?

Comment: @sammydude I've added example of second view.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This should help :) Before POST, would it be possible to access this variable? I tried accessing it directly in the HTML but couldn't. But of course I need the value to handle things internally (like how you've shown in POST). Just that I was curious to display on screen also :)

Comment: @sammydude you can do the same inside `get_context_data` method.

Comment: Thanks @neverwalkaloner. I'm getting a KeyError error (KeyError at /ingestion/ 'sessionid') in POST for this line.   sessionid=request.session['sessionid']

Comment: I tried this and getting 'no value'.  sessionid=request.session.get('sessionid','no value')